# Multiple Listeners in one RabbitListenerContainer not working

Tags: spring-amqp

I have hit my head against the wall about this for the entire day, very annoying, but am now putting this question to the community, hopefully someone could help me

This is my config:

```
    <rabbit:connection-factory id="connectionFactory"
        virtual-host="****" username="****" password="****" />
    <rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="connectionFactory" />
    <rabbit:admin connection-factory="connectionFactory" />

    <rabbit:queue name="a" durable="true" />
    <rabbit:queue name="b" durable="true" />

    <rabbit:listener-container prefetch="10"
        task-executor="taskExecutor" acknowledge="auto"
        transaction-size="10" connection-factory="connectionFactory"
        concurrency="10" channel-transacted="false"
        message-converter="jsonMessageConverter" requeue-rejected="false">

        <rabbit:listener id="a-listener" ref="Abean"
            method="listen" queue-names="a" />
        <rabbit:listener id="b-listener" ref="Bbean"
            method="listen" queue-names="b" />
    </rabbit:listener-container>

    <bean id="Abean"
        class="****" />
    <bean id="Bbean"
        class="****" />

    <rabbit:direct-exchange name="****"
        durable="true">
        <rabbit:bindings>
            <rabbit:binding queue="a" key="a" />
            <rabbit:binding queue="b"
                key="b" />
        </rabbit:bindings>
    </rabbit:direct-exchange>
```

After starting the context, no errors, it appears that only the first listener (a-listener) configured will have consumers connected to the queue (a) it is interested in. However, the other listener, there is nothing, no consumers connecting to the queue (b).

What is the problem with this configuration?

I am using the latest spring-amqp (1.5.4.Release)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just copied your configuration and ran this test...

```
@ContextConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class Foo {

    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate template;

    @Autowired
    private FooListener Abean;

    @Autowired
    private FooListener Bbean;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        template.convertAndSend("sotest", "a", "foo");
        template.convertAndSend("sotest", "b", "bar");
        assertTrue(Abean.latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
        assertTrue(Bbean.latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
    }

    public static class FooListener {

        private final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        public void listen(byte[] foo) {
            System.out.println("received:" + foo);
            latch.countDown();
        }
    }

}
```

... and it worked fine.

You don't show your `taskExcecutor` bean; perhaps your task executor only has one thread?

Comment: Hi Gary, thank you for helping, my task executor is configured for core pool size of 5 and max pool size of 50

Comment: Hi Gary, I found the problem, I really think this is a bug, way too deceptive for my liking: 

My configuration was (for 2 queues):

consumer concurrency=5
taskexecutor.core.pool.size=5
taskexecutor.max.pool.size=50

It seems that the task executor pool will not scale beyond 5 to address the consumer need on the other queue, meaning the first queue configured will get 5 consumers but the next one gets none. Only when I bump the taskexecutor.core.pool.size up to 10 does the other set of consumers actually start up and start listening to the queue.

Your thoughts...

Comment: From [the Spring AMQP documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#_threading_and_asynchronous_consumers), `If not configured, a SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor is used. If a pooled executor is used, ensure the pool size is sufficient to handle the configured concurrency.`. From the `ThreadPoolExecutor` javadoc: `If there are more than corePoolSize but less than
maximumPoolSize threads running, a new thread will be created only if the queue is full.` Unless you have a bounded queue in the executor, you'll never get more threads. The core size has to be big enough.

Comment: Since these threads are long-lived, there's not really a reason to use a thread pool; that's why we use a `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` internally.